# Makefile not accepting conditionals

Tags: bash, make

I am using the following conditional statement within a `Makefile`:

```
mytarget:
    if [ -z "${TAG1}" | -z "${TAG2}" | -z "${TAG3}" ]
        then
        echo "Need to set all tag names images
        exit 1
    fi
```

but then ...

```
$ make mytarget TAG1=latest TAG2=latest TAG3=latest
if [ -z "latest" | -z "latest" | -z "latest" ]
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'env' failed
make: *** [env] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have backslashes at the end of each (but the last) command line.

`make` sends each command line to a separate shell using: `/bin/sh -ce "cmdline"`

Note that since you don't have the newlines in the shell anymore, you may need to add a semicolon at before the `backslash newline` for some commands, e.g.

```
target:
    if true; \
        then \
            echo true;\
    fi
```

the backslash causes that `make` converts all these virtual lines to:

```
if true; then echo true; fi
```

before sending it to `/bin/sh -ce cmd`.